Ntoskrnl High CPU Usage Windows 11 (ntoskml.exe!Ke Save State ForHibemate+Oxec0 shown in Process Explorer)
The bug started appearing randomly. I tried to solve it by following various tutorials from different sites, but none worked, makes my laptop hot so the fans spin louder and faster, and my battery drains fast
Aside from all the various suggested solutions I also disabled hibernation (judging from the thread shown as the culprit, but none worked), i still haven't explored all I can

Please never post things like "following various tutorials from different sites, but none worked" or similar. Instead describe everything you did and the results in order to avoid wasting yours and other people's time posting or asking about the same things you already tried.
